# Не выводятся сообщения из второго потока

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

У меня есть 2 потока:

```
private class Init implements Runnable {

 public void run() {
  setTextMessage("Инициализация");
  //выполняем действия 
 }

}

private class Download implements Runnable {

   public void run() {
      setTextMessage("Скачивание");
      //выполняем действия
      Thread thread = new Thread(new Init());
      thread.start();

   }

}

public void setTextMessage(final String textMessage) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (dialog != null) {
                setDialogMessage(textMessage);
            }
        }
    });
}

 //Add 1
 protected void setDialogMessage(Dialog dst, String text) {
    if (dst != null) {
        TextView progressTextDetails = (TextView) dst.findViewById(R.id.progressTextDetails);
        progressTextDetails.setText(text);
    }
}
```

В идеале, после запуска второго потока, на экране меняется сообщение на *"Инициализация"* и выполняются действия определенные во втором потоке. Но иногда сообщение на экране не меняется. Хотя действия определенные во втором потоке начинают выполнятся. Почему?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Вы стартуете новый поток в классе `Download`, который непонятно где и как используете. И непонятно как вы меняете сообщение на экране? Добавьте полный код, потому что сейчас это какие-то несвязные отрывки.

Comment: Очень много взаимосвязей, чтобы скидывать весь код. Поток Download начинает свой старт из OnCreate activity.

Answer (score 0):

работа с UI (setText) должна выполняться только на UI потоке.
используйте runOnUiThread()

PS: скорее всего вы решаете нужную вам задачу неверным способом. почитайте хотя бы про AsyncTask, Loaders

Comment: setTextMessage внутри использует runOnUiThread(). Иначе бы вообще не выводились сообщения.

Comment: Добавил реализацию setTextMessage. Данный метод вызывается во втором потоке, но изменение текста в UI потоке не происходит.

Comment: Почему Вы так уверены?

Comment: из опыта помощи людям в https://t.me/android_ru